# React - DefaultValue working in standard input and MUI library but not in AntD

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, antd

I have a form build with antD, however, since it is too large and the user can generate more input fields on it, it becomes really slow due to useState, even with the use of React.memo.

So I came to another approach. Load the default values that must be shown in the form on load (fetch), and instead of useState, approach the situation with useRef. So the user will have the default values on screen and they could be modified, once the user presses "save", the new value of each ref will be loaded and sent to the server.

However, when testing the options, I found the following issue, that i present to you [in the following codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-gianmarco-5bz7ts?file=/src/App.js).

The issue is that it seems the default value property is not working for antD input, even if the logic is identical in the other two input cases:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getDataFromApi = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/1")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              miRef.current.value = json.title;
              miRef2.current.value = json.title;
              miRef3.current.value = json.title;
            }, 1000),
              setA(json.title);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener los datos:", error);
      }
    };

    getDataFromApi();
  }, []);


//in return
    <TextField inputRef={miRef} type="text" /> //Mui TextField
    <input ref={miRef2} type="text" /> //Standard input
    <Input ref={miRef3} type="text" /> // AntD Input
```

The two firsts load the value as default as expected, however, it does not when it comes to antD input.

*Please note this is an approach I'm trying to make work in order to avoid the use of useState.*

Comment: There's no ref prop that you can pass to Form.Item and there's no need to useRef. Just use antd useForm hook. Second if you pass `name` prop to `Form.Item` that field is controlled one and is handled by `Antd Form`. If you want to set initialValues, use Form `initialValues` prop. Since your defaultValues depends on server response, you can use `form.setFieldsValues({...})`. [Updated Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-noyce-8c9fir?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique in your example, if I want to add addonBefore and other input properties, should I do it in the <Input> or in the <Form.Item>?

Comment: in `Input` Component. You can follow the [Form.Item API](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem) which prop you can pass to Form.Item. Same for input field. Each antd component have an api section with a list of all props that you can pass to the component